# ssmtp: queuing emails when smtp server is unreachable

Tags: linux, ssmtp

I have ssmtp installed and configured on my linux box. It connects to a remote smtp server provided by my hosting provider and works faultlessly.

My linux box is connected to an APC UPS, and emails are sent from the ups deamon (apcupsd) when the machine looses comms with the UPS, or the battery in the UPS becomes faulty.

apcupsd also sends out "onbattery" or "onmains" emails. The problem is however that the linux box is the only thing on the UPS, things like my router and hub are NOT on the UPS, and so switch off in the event of a power outage.

Is there anyway to have the emails queued up when the linux box is unable to connect to the smtp server, and then deliver them when everything comes online?

if I try "mailq" during a power outage, it states that the queue is empty, even tho I know that an email was generated and failed to be delivered.

Thanks in advance,

Phil.

Comment: This looks like a question for serverfault.com rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I'd never heard of serverfault.com 'till now.